# How can I make a 3D object have different color front and back faces

Tags: matlab, octave

Is it possible to make a 3D object have different colors on each side (front and back faces one side of an object one color like *red* and another side another color like *blue*) using surf?

```
%example
[x y] = meshgrid(-1:0.1:1); % Generate x and y data
z = zeros(size(x, 1)); % Generate z data
surf(x, y, z, 'FaceColor', 'red') % Plot the surface
```

[image: Red side]

How can I make the other side of the surf object another color like blue?  Is this possible?

I'm using Octave 5.1 which is similar to Matlab

Comment: I dont think you can, as this is not how geometric primitives work in e.g. OpenGL. The best way I can think of is by plotting 2 surfaces at a very close distance of each other and coloring them differently

Comment: I guess I need to find out if it supports GLSL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903403/how-put-different-colors-at-front-and-back-sides-of-quad..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631981/what-is-the-difference-between-opengl-and-glsl

Comment: It probably "supports" it, because it uses OpenGL, but the function `surf` does not use GLSL. Unless you are able to rewrite the source code for `surf` to add this option to the plot, and recompile Octave,  the answer is you can not do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL is used by virtually every computer to draw stuff in the screen, and so does MATLAB (and Octave AFAIK). As MATLAB uses OpenGL primitives to plot things on screen, you can not do whatever a OpenGL primitive can not do, e.g. drawing a primitive with different color in each side. With this understanding, the conclusion is that to do what you want, you need to plot the surface twice.

```
surf(x, y, z, 'FaceColor', 'red') % Plot the surface
hold on
surf(x, y, z-z*0.001, 'FaceColor', 'blue') % Plot the surface
```